# Yii2 - yii\console\Application::getSession()

Tags: php, yii2, console-application, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to run a console application from the terminal, but am getting this error

```
Calling unknown method: yii\console\Application::getSession()
```

this is the controller

```
class BeanstalkController extends \yii\console\Controller {

public function actionIndex() {

    echo 'this is console action';
} }
```

and this is the console config

```
return [
'id' => 'app-console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
'modules' => [],
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
        'enableAutoLogin' => TRUE,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params,];
```

I tried to remove the session from the config but am still getting the session error.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant/blob/master/docs/60-troubleshooting.md#calling-unknown-method-yiiconsoleapplicationgetsession

Comment: so if i have to remove Yii::$app->getSession() from common\models\Users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why every option i tried is not working is that my Yii2 version is old, i had to upgrade to the latest version to get everything working perfectly.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Correct config in console env is:

```
'components' => [
            'user' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
                'enableSession' => false,
                'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Application::getSession()` because `yii\console\Aplication`is different than web aplication.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-console-application.html

Try to add session component to your config.

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
            'enableAutoLogin' => TRUE,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'session' => [ 
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

And use it as a component

```
Yii::$app->session->get('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

In `console/config/main.php`:

```
return [
   'components' => [
       'user' => null,
       // and put there other components which use a PHP-session
    ]
]
```